# Create an answer file to format drive before install?

Tags: windows

Okay so I am digging into windows AIK, I need to make sure it will format the drive (all drives have 2 partitions), then install.

Bonus question, anyone know where I can get some GMA 4500 CAB's?

Answer (score 0):

Inside WAIK, under the section `Microsoft-Windows-Setup\DiskConfiguration\Disk\ModifyPartitions\ModifyPartition`
you need to set a few options
`Format=%FILESYSTEM TYPE%`
and  `PartitionID=%ID OF PARTITION TO FORMAT%` for both partitions.

Comment: Which pass? Is it best set in the PE of the image answer file? Or is it better done as a WDSUnattend file attached to the client tab?